# return multiple value from function back to call

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I'm a noobie... and I'm sure there is better terminology for what I'm trying to ask (callback?) but basically I want to learn how to get values calcluated in a function back to where the function was called from. E.g.:

```
$(function() {
    setValues();
    console.log(val1, val2, val3);

});

function setValues() {
    var val1 = 10;
    var val2 = 20;
    var val3 = 30;  
}
```

Comment: You can return an object literal with the values exposed as properties and access them that way.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Could you give me an example of how that would work with my example code?

Comment: Check out firefoxuser_1's answer.  It should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var myvalues = setValues(); //this stores the values you got from the function

   //now you can do something like console.log(myvalues.value1) to get the first value


});

function setValues() {
    var val1 = 10;
    var val2 = 20;
    var val3 = 30;  
    return {value1: val1, value2: val2, value3: val3} //this sends the data back to the original place where you called the function
}
```

I would suggest reading [this article on object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FValues%2C_variables%2C_and_literals#Object_literals).

Comment: Thank you firefoxuser_1! Very helpful.